# how to set padding to listview items?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, padding

I have a Listview on Large icon view in Windows Forms that the images are so close to each other.
so how could I set padding to items ?

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57849/net-listview-row-padding

Comment: possible duplicate of [listview tile layout problem (vb.net)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754006/listview-tile-layout-problem-vb-net)

Answer (score 3):

There is no method within ListView to do this. You could take a look at [LVM_SETICONSPACING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761176%28VS.85%29.aspx). [Here](http://qdevblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/c-listview-item-spacing.html) is a very good tutorial, if you need help.

Comment: This is kind of crazy but it woks well for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IndentCount property.

Comment: where IndentCount  ?

Comment: It's a property of ListViewItem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.indentcount?view=windowsdesktop-8.0