# Item spacing in ListView where View=List

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a listview with checkboxes and the view=list. There is no vertical spacing at all between the items. How can I increase the vertical spacing?

[image: Listview spacing]

A lot of answers are talking about LVM_SETICONSPACING, but that only works in Icon view. [Check Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57849/net-listview-row-padding)

I also tried [BetterListview express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) as an alternative, but that gives so much spacing that another item could go in between, in Express mode you cannot change the spacing, only in the 300 Dollar paid version... :(

Comment: focus on your explaining question in full, there's a lot of fluff here.  Consider adding code.

Comment: Can u paste an image of what's going wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the fluffy question, lot of frustration today :) Updated the question with an image

Comment: Maybe use the `PadRight()` extension and give the values in the list additional whitespace?  Or are you talking about spacing above or below?

Comment: @Jacob, yeah I am trying to change the vertical spacing, updated the question

Comment: Have a look at my answer; it shows you how to do it in 3 or 4 lines..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need to do is

- Add an `ImageList` to the `Form`
- Set its `ImageSize.Height` to the height you want
- Set the `ListView`'s `SmallImageList` to the `ImageList`

Done.

**Note**:

- You do **not** need to set the `ImageIndex` on any `Item`.
- You do **not** need to add any `Images`.

Make sure to set the `ImageSize.Width` to a small number, so you don't get a gap between the `CheckBox` and the `Item`'s `Text`.

So to set up the `ListView` write:

```
int itemHeight = 20;
ImageList imgList = new ImageList();
imgList.ImageSize = new Size(1, itemHeight);
listView1.SmallImageList = imgList;
```

Comment: Hey TaW, works brilliantly! Luckily a nice and simple solution, thanks!

Comment: but this no long allows me to have View.List to be a single row not it appears as though I have two columns

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPF/XAML you can try something like:

```
...
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2, 2, 2, 2"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
...
```

Change the margin to your needs and the spacing will appear.

Comment: good to see that's improved in WPF, unfortunately I'm in Winforms